# Can i reverse a List within a particular Range in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i mean Suppose I have a List `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
i want to reverse its number in a particular range like from 2 to 5 so the expected output is `[1,2,6,5,4,3,7,8,9]`

NB: I don't want to use a Loop and by swapping each values, don't want to use extra space.
is it possible? like the reverse() function

Comment: Slices create new `list` objects, using extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by just considering the slice of the list and reversing it.

example:

```
a[2:6] = a[2:6][::-1]
```

This also can be achieved much faster, considering the answer from @Tom Karzes.

```
a[2:6] = a[5:1:-1]
```

Comment: Slices use a linear amount of extra space.

Comment: `a[2:6][::-1]` -> `a[5:1:-1]`.  This is faster and takes half as much extra space.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such function. If you want to reverse only a portion of a list in-place, you'll need to do so explicitly.

```
x = list(range(1, 10))
i = x.index(3)  # i = 2
j = x.index(6)   # j = 5
while i < j:
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    i += 1
    j -= 1
```

---

You cannot use list slicing, because a slice operation creates a new list.

(Yes, `i` and `j` use extra space, as does the tuple unpacking, but it's a *constant* amount of space, independent of the size of the range. *Some* extra space is unavoidable.)

You also cannot use something like

```
lst[2:6] = islice(lst, 5, 1, -1)
```

because the step size cannot be negative. The reason is that `islice` works for *arbitrary* iterators, which means it can only advance through the list in one direction. Iterating backwards would mean having to cache values as you try to locate the end of the range.

Comment: I think the 2 to 5 in OP's post are meant to be indices, not list values.  I.e., I don't think calling `index` is correct.

Comment: True, but and `i` and `j` get initialized to `2` and `5`, respectively. I just assumed a subrange within a range.

Comment: I think it's clearer to just assign 2 and 5 directly, and leave it to OP to decide how to determine the indices (which seems to be outside the scope of the post).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny And it is *not* possible, but using a loop is preferable to using unnecessary space.

Comment: There is no method or function like `x.reverse(2, 5)` or `reverse(x, 2, 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the requirement of no extra space and no loops, you can use slice assignment with any iterable, so something like the following will work:

```
from itertools import islice

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

lst[2:6] = islice(reversed(lst), len(lst)-6, len(lst)-2)
# [1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

It must be noted though that at the C-level, Python will load the iterable into a space-occupying data structure before filling the values into the old list.

Oddly enough, the list CPython implementation has a util [`reverse_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c#L1059) that does (as per its own comment) *"Reverse a slice of a list in place [...]"*. It is used in other list functions like sorting, but sadly not exposed to the Python language.

Comment: As noted, this still uses extra storage for the slice.  Is this really better than `lst[2:6] = lst[5:1:-1]`?

Comment: There is no slice; `reversed(lst)` produces a value of type `list_reverseiterator`, not a new list. It uses constant space because it's just a wrapper around the list that takes advantage of the fact that lists are finite.

Comment: Slice assignment just uses the iterator protocol to retrieve one value at a time from the `islice` object.

Comment: @chepner The copying is performed by the slice assignment.  It has to be, since if it were done strictly in-place, the result would be incorrect (and Python would have no idea how long it was).  Internally, Python copies the entire right hand side into a temporary, and only then updates the list.  This was explained in the answer itself.  As I said, I don't think this uses any less space than the more obvious slice assignment, without `islice`.

Comment: Good point; the earlier part of the range is overwritten before the reversed iterator would reach it.

Answer (score -1):

You can split your list in multiple.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = a[:2] + a[2:6][::-1] + a[6:]

[1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: That uses extra space. Each slice operation creates a new `list` object.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use extra space.  This uses about as much extra space as possible.  It's also poorly expressed (e.g., `a[2:6][::-1]` is awkward and inefficient).